# Alternativa pra Strings?

Tags: c#, string, comparação, enums

Várias coisas no projeto tem uma tabela com possíveis nomes (strings). Mas não quero usar strings pra fazer comparações por vários motivos (case-sensitive, erro de digitação, alterações na tabela de nomes, etc). Então quis usar enums, mas o C# só deixa fazer overload em operadores de classes, não enums. Posso até fazer uma função pra comparar uma string com um enum correspondente, mas queria uma solução mais elegante.

```
if("nome" == tipoEnum.fulano)
```

ficaria melhor do que

```
if(funcaoDeComparar(string, enum))
```

Comment: Você diz que não quer usar *strings*, mas é o que está usando, não entendi.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia criar constantes e usar estas constantes para comparação, como por exemplo:

```
const string NOME1 = "Fulano";
if ("nome" == NOME1)
...
```

Outra opção seria usar o enum como disse e na comparação fazer:

```
if ("nome" == tipoEnum.fulano.ToString())
```

Uma terceira opção seria converter o string para enum e depois comparar como enum ou em switch. Segue exemplo de conversão de um string para enum:

```
private Enum_ItemType ConvertItemTypeStringToEnum(string itemTypeString)
    {
        Enum_ItemType itemType;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemTypeString))
        {
            return Enum_ItemType.Unidentified;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                System.Enum.TryParse<Enum_ItemType>(itemTypeString, out itemType);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                itemType = Enum_ItemType.Unidentified;
            }
        }

        return itemType;
    }
```